# Is this subset of $\mathbb{R^2}$ compact?

Tags: real-analysis

Let the set to be $\{(x,y):2x^2+y^2=1\}$. Is this subset compact? I was thinking about totally bounded and complete. So that is why I could not prove.

Comment: This is not a subset of $\mathbb{R}$. It is a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$. Do you know the definition of "compact"?

Comment: I was thinking about totally bounded and complete. So that is why I couldnt prove. Also I tried to do R^2 I couldn't do it with latex sorry about that. Yes close and bounded right?

Comment: @Mrnobody: Think closed and bounded instead.

Comment: thank you very much!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Remember to include your work on the problem, otherwise it looks like you are asking others to do your homework for you.

Comment: @jjagmath: It was the first time for me thanks a lot I will include.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the function $f(x,y) = 2x^{2} + y^{2} - 1$ which is continuous.

Consequently, $\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^{2} \mid 2x^{2} + y^{2} = 1\} = f^{-1}(\{0\})$.

Since $\{0\}$ is closed (because its complement is open), we conclude the proposed set is closed.

Moreover, it is also bounded since $\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^{2} \mid 2x^{2} + y^{2} = 1\}\subseteq B(0,1)$.

Indeed, if $(x,y)$ belong to such set, we have that
\begin{align*}
\|(x,y) - (0,0)\| & = \sqrt{x^{2} + y^{2}}\\\\
& = \sqrt{x^{2} + 1 - 2x^{2}}\\\\
& = \sqrt{1 - x^{2}} < 1
\end{align*}

since $x\in[-1/\sqrt{2},1/\sqrt{2}]$. Hence it is compact.

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: This is also nice thanks!